# Sqlite Group By reverses the order

Tags: ios, sqlite, group-by

This is my query :

```
SELECT * FROM Message WHERE ParentMessage = ? GROUP BY MessageId
```

This reverses the order of the results.
Not sure why

Records on screen before Group By :

A
B
C
D

Records on screen after Group By :

D
C
B
A

Comment: what order? maybe add a `ORDER BY MessageId ASC|DESC`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, the results of a query do not have any guaranteed order unless you are using ORDER BY.

(In this case, it's likely that the query optimizer has estimated that using an index in a certain way would make the execution faster.)

Answer (score 0):

If your tableName is Message and Column name is ParentMessage finally your row name is Message ID,the result is below like this

```
select * from Message WHERE ParentMessage in (MessageId) order by ParentMessage DESC
```

Otherwise

```
select * from Message WHERE ParentMessage order by MessageId DESC
```